# Place GCC assembler code section in RAM

Tags: gcc, linker, ram, gnu-assembler

I have an assembly function written for an embedded ARM project that I would like to tag with the attribute to place it in a RAM code section rather than flash. How do I specify this?

To do this for C I would use the section attribute:

```
int f (void) __attribute__ ((section (".ram"))) {...}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact answer depends on your target (bare metal? ELF?), but the following will likely work

```
.section .ram
YOUR ASSEMBLY CODE
```